# After making bootable USB flash drive it is not recognized

Tags: usb, bootable-media

I used some software (I forgot name...) to make bootable USB flash drive. In the middle of process it showed error and from than I cant use USB flash drive on only on this computer. I hear sound but nothing else is visible.

I tried formating it from another PC but it didn't help. Anyone know what might be problem?

Comment: Is this on windows? Does it show under disk management after plugged in? It could be that it just isn't assigned a drive-letter on Windows.

Comment: @xstnc
Yes, I wasn't detail enought in question. It is on Windows 8.1. It is visible in Device Manager as USB Mass Storage Device and it say that it works but I can't see it in My Computer

Comment: Sounds like it's not assigned a drive-letter then. Check in "disk management" try - "diskmgmt.msc" from run or cmd :) You can also find it from the control-panel and administrative tools -> manage computer.

Comment: @xstnc
you were right, there was no label assigned. But even afer I assigned label and formated USB it is still no visible in My Computer. (and in disk manager status is healthy).

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Ok! That's one part down atleast. Could you provide a screenshot of your disk manager with the USB highlighted? Just attach it to your original question :)

Comment: @xstnc I actually need 10 reputation to post images so I will provide you link. [img](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdp9d.png)

Comment: At the picture, it still doesn't have a drive letter! :) Here is one that works for me. Notice the driveletter. http://tinypic.com/r/28l9x1/5 Make sure the letter you are assigning it isn't in use already.

Comment: @xstnc this worked! Thanks! If you want write comment below so I can accept your answer as correct

Comment: Good! I made a quick summary below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing and formatting a USB drive a lot, make sure you have added a drive letter to it.

If the USB doesn't show up in Windows Explorer, this is usually the case.

I've attached a picture of one of my working USB drives. Notice the assigned drive letter (E:)!

[image: USB in Disk Management]

To assign and check what drives are taken, I prefer to use Disk Management. 
You find this tool under Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management.

In the side menu, go all the way down to Disk Management.

Right click the disk you want to assign a letter to, and choose "Edit drive letter and paths".
From this menu, you can select what letter it should use.